# Using Ruby Watir gem, Clicking a div, Step passes but div doesnt open

Tags: html, ruby, watir, page-object-gem

gem 'watir-webdriver', '0.6.4'
gem 'page-object', '0.9.4'

Never came across this problem.

So I am clicking the div :id, 'promo-code-header'  using page object, I've tried using :class, :id, and the Span inside the Div. The says it clicks the element and passes the step and says the elements are visible but it does not open the div that when clicked is supposed to show a promocode textfield.

```
<div class="promo-container">
  <div class="promo-code">
    <div class="accordion" data-accordion="" aria-multiselectable="false">
      <div class="accordion-container">
        <div class="promo-code-title accordion-title" role="tab" aria-controls="promo-code-body" id="promo-code-header">
          <span class="icon icon-plus"></span> Add Promo or Coupon Code
            <a class="promo-help-link" href="">
            <span data-tooltip="" class="has-tip tip-right round icon icon-info" aria-hidden="true" data-selector="tooltip-680112" aria-describedby="tooltip-680112" title=""></span><span class="sr-only">Help</span>
            </a>
          </div>
```

This is the step code I use to click everything

'@current_page.close_foresee

move_page_object_element_into_view page_element

if @current_page.send(DataHelper.convert_to_snake_case(page_element).concat('_element')).is_a?(PageObject::Elements::RadioButton)
    @current_page.send(DataHelper.convert_to_snake_case(page_element).prepend('select_'))

else
    @current_page.send(DataHelper.convert_to_snake_case(page_element))

end'

Comment: Which div are you clicking/trying to click? Which elements are supposed to be visible?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the watir-webdriver code.

Comment: Is `@current_page.close_foresee` supposed to be the part that clicks the div? If so, it would help to know what the page object class is. If not, I do not see how this code is related to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I used @browser.div(:id, 'promo-code-header').click and it worked..

Comment: If anyone has feed back on why the code I normally use to click objects (which is posted in the question) doesn't work in this case, but that basic code did, that would be great!